# JS Adding a class to a class

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get this very basic code to run, where I add a class to the selected elements.

https://jsfiddle.net/wm27ch2p/1/

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("liHome")[0].classname += ' active';
document.getElementsByClassName("aHome")[0].classname += ' active';
```

```html
<li class="liHome"><a class="aHome" href="#yellowBar">Home</a></li>
```

EDIT: Thank you for pointing out the typo, in addition to this question is there any way I can add this class name to all of the elements with liHome or aHome class, instead of just [0].

Comment: When posting your question you should explain in detail what is not working.

Answer (score 3):

[`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) is camel-cased:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("liHome")[0].className += ' active';
document.getElementsByClassName("aHome")[0].className += ' active';
```

```html
<li class="liHome"><a class="aHome" href="#yellowBar">Home</a></li>
```

Alternately you can use use [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("liHome")[0].classList.add('active');
document.getElementsByClassName("aHome")[0].classList.add('active');
```

```html
<li class="liHome"><a class="aHome" href="#yellowBar">Home</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct property will be `className`, not `classname`:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("liHome")[0].className += ' active';
// etc
```

Answer (score 0):

JS is case sensitive and the attribute is called `className`, not `classname`:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("liHome")[0].className += ' active';
document.getElementsByClassName("aHome")[0].className += ' active';
```

```html
<li class="liHome"><a class="aHome" href="#yellowBar">Home</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) to add a new class:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("liHome")[0].classList.add('active');
document.getElementsByClassName("aHome")[0].classList.add('active');
```

```css
.active {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<li class="liHome"><a class="aHome" href="#yellowBar">Home</a></li>
```